# Editar planílha Excel com C# no Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação web que lê uma planilha do excel e importa os valores da células para o banco de dados automaticamente.
Estou usando COM, logo é necessário na maquina o Microsoft Excel instalado. Quando compilo localmente funciona sem problemas. Porem, hospedei no azure recentemente e o erro se da justamente por não ter o Excel instalado. Como posso contornar este erro? Não entendo muito do azure, então queria saber uma forma de instalar Microsoft Office Excel.

ERRO QUE APARECE:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Answer (score -2):

Apenas para resumir: Azure App Services WebApp é uma Plataforma como Serviço. Isso quer dizer que a total responsabilidade pela manutenção da infraestrutura é da Microsoft e não do desenvolvedor. Mas para poderem assumir esse papel, eles deve engessar bastante o ambiente de hospedagem, e abrir apenas pontos realmente relevantes para o desenvolvedor - e instalar softwares em seus servidores está totalmente fora de questão.

Existe uma opção que eu recomendo muito para trabalhar com Excel a partir de sistemas .NET: [SpreadSheet Light](http://spreadsheetlight.com/).

Apesar de ser uma biblioteca com métodos procedurais - não é orientado à objetos, é bem intuitiva e até mesmo elegante de se trabalhar. Veja algunas exemplos:

**Ler e modificar dados de uma planilha**

```
// SpreadsheetLight works on the idea of a currently selected worksheet.
// If no worksheet name is provided on opening an existing spreadsheet,
// the first available worksheet is selected.

        SLDocument sl = new SLDocument("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetOriginal.xlsx", "Sheet2");

        sl.SetCellValue("E6", "Let's party!!!!111!!!1");

        sl.SelectWorksheet("Sheet3");
        sl.SetCellValue("E6", "Before anyone calls the popo!");

        sl.AddWorksheet("DanceFloor");
        sl.SetCellValue("B4", "Who let the dogs out?");
        sl.SetCellValue("B5", "Woof!");

        sl.SaveAs("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetModified.xlsx");

        Console.WriteLine("End of program");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

[Veja aqui mais exemplos de como trabalhar planilha Excel com c#](http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/).